# Как в контроллере считать что выбрано в списке Select в представлении?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Проект ASP.NET MVC. Нужно чтоб в контроллере считывалось, что сейчас выбрано в списке.

```
<select id="SL">
    <option value="1">Name</option>
    <option value="2">Category</option>
    <option value="3">Country</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $("#SL").change(function () {
    var value = {
        'val': $("#SL").val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "WhatIsSelected",
        data: JSON.stringify(value),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json"
    });
});
```